# node.js v0.12.x changes in EventEmitter ruins inheritance

Tags: node.js, inheritance, eventemitter, changelog

There is some changes in node.js 0.12.x related to events module.
This changes makes my code that extends EventEmitter class non-workable.
Here is code that works fine in node.js v0.10.35:
teh_emitter.js:

```js
var EventEmitter = require('events');
var util = require('util');

util.inherits(TehEmitter, EventEmitter);


function TehEmitter(){

 EventEmitter.call(this);
}


TehEmitter.prototype.on('start', function (fCallback) {

 fCallback();
});

module.exports = TehEmitter;
```

test_teh_emitter.js:

```js
var TehEmitter =  require('./teh_emitter');

describe('EventEmitter tests', function(){

 describe('#emit() function', function(){

  it('should fire start event', function(fCallback){

   var oEmitter = new TehEmitter(fCallback);

   oEmitter.emit('start', fCallback);

  });
 })
});
```

But on node.js v0.12.7 it says:
    0 passing (2s)
    1 failing

```
1) EventEmitter tests #emit() function should fire start event:
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

I know that in 0.12.x one should assign:
`var EventEmitter = require('events');`
(though `require('events').EventEmitter;` should still work for backwards compatability).
But it doesn't helps.

How am I gonna fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was changed in [2c6b424](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/2c6b424829caf0a4c07839c4daac3a438c0f0c9a) because of a bug involving event handlers bleeding into all other instances of the same object/"class" (see [7157](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7157)).

Probably your best bet for compatibility is to just add the event handler in the constructor:

```
function TehEmitter(){
  EventEmitter.call(this);
  this.on('start', onStart);
}

function onStart(fCallback) {
  fCallback();
}
```